# AWS EB can't talk to the app servers... what could block that

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We had a working env yesterday morning.  One person was working with some VPC peering stuff. And somehow it seems blocked the ELB from being able to talk to the application servers.  So we can't deploy.
We get this error

```
Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
```

And EB can't retrieve any logs from the app server either.  So clearly it is getting blocked.  The IAM of the instance has AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier and is the same IAM used in another env that works.

Also, I can RDP to the app instance from my laptop. Though I added my IP to one of the security groups for the instance.  I audited the SG's for the working env, and don't see anything specific for EB.

Everything points to something with the VPC... but what should I look at?

Comment: I would start my looking at the route tables, as that's something that needs to be modified for peering.

Comment: What should I look at in the route tables... Cause I know the server be reached from outside by my laptop... but where does EB come from?  Like EB doesn't have a subnet or anything that I could ensure reachability to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that that error message doesn't always mean it can't talk to the instance.  We had updated the AMI a while back and used the wrong one... it wasn't compatible with the platform.  So nothing worked right, including getting the logs. So the fix was to sync up the AMI and the EB platform.